# I want lua function to run once

Tags: lua, azerothcore, eluna-lua-engine

I'm quite new to lua scripting.. now i'm trying to code in game boss

```
local function SlitherEvents(event, creature, attacker, damage)
    if(creature:GetHealthPct() <= 60) then
        creature:SendUnitYell("Will punish you all",0)
        creature:RegisterEvent(AirBurst, 1000, 0) -- 1 seconds
        return
    end
end
```

this should make the boss talk when his health = 60% or less but it should  run one time, when I run the code the boss keep saying and attacking all the time. How can I make it run once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a boolean created outside the scope of the function callback:

```
local has_talked = false
local function SlitherEvents(event, creature, attacker, damage)
  if creature:GetHealthPct() <= 60 and not has_talked then
    has_talked = true
    creature:SendUnitYell("Will punish you all",0)
    creature:RegisterEvent(AirBurst, 1000, 1) -- 1 seconds
    return
  end
end
```

---

### EDIT

If you are actually using the [Eluna Engine's `RegisterEvent`](http://www.elunaengine.com/WorldObject/RegisterEvent.html) call, then set the number of repeats to **1** and not 0. This will resolve the [issue you had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42194327/i-want-lua-function-to-run-once/42194536?noredirect=1#comment71552392_42194536).

Comment: he yelled only 1 time which is good and he kept using the spell

Comment: This seems like a bad workaround, the event is still firing, rather than make the event do nothing, disconnect the event itself. He's likely calling this function in a loop, the check should go in the loop ot he function, perhaps mention this is the answer?

Comment: @warspyking How do you deregister them in love/garry's-mode/whatever-OP-is-using!

Comment: It looks as though it is for the [Eluna Lua Engine](https://github.com/ElunaLuaEngine/Eluna)

Comment: @MiDo Note that `SlitherEvents` is likely used for multiple creatures. All of the them share `has_talked` value. This means that if one of 10 creatures using this script talks, then none of the others will talk. To fix this you need to store the boolean value per creature. For example `creature:SetData('talked', true)` and later `if creature:GetData('talked') then`. Details of GetData and SetData can be found in https://github.com/ElunaLuaEngine/Eluna/blob/master/extensions/ObjectVariables.ext#L9-L19